# mshtml how to hook into document's readystatechange event

Tags: c#, winapi, mshtml

I'm converting an `IE` window's handle to `mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass` using the way as described [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_22877061.html).

There are a couple of really weird things happening here.

1. When I hook into the `onreadystatechange` event for frame document (get the `frame` using `document.getElementById` and hook into frame `onreadystatechange`), the event gets fired only once.
2. Problem #1 disappears when I detach the event handler and reattach it to the same method.
3. **THE MAIN PROBLEM** , after doing this the web document freezes, textboxes don't receive focus , buttons can be clicked but they appear like read only buttons All text type controls become readonly, after digging through the problem a little  , I found that this behaviour appears as soon as you hook into the frame document's `onreadystatechange` event. Detaching from the event brings the page back to normal behaviour.

Here's the code which I'm using.

```
this.GuideDocument = this.GetHtmlDocumentByWindowHandle(handle) as mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass;
var frame = (this.GuideDocument.frames.item(0) as mshtml.IHTMLWindow2).frames.item(1) as mshtml.IHTMLWindow2;
var frameDocument = frame.document as mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass;
frameDocument.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event_onreadystatechange += frameDocument_HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event_onreadystatechange;


void frameDocument_HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event_onreadystatechange(IHTMLEventObj pEvtObj)
{
    frameDocument.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event_onreadystatechange -= frameDocument_HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event_onreadystatechange;
    frameDocument.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event_onreadystatechange += frameDocument_HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event_onreadystatechange;
    this.DisableButton("btnClose", string.Empty, framedocument);
    }
```

I'm not exactly sure as to what's missing here, Do you see anything wrong here, or any alternate approach. This web page is composed of many `framesets` and thus `frames`. any insights into this will be a gr8 help.

I somehow feel, that it requires some `base.onreadystatechange` thing, but I don't know if there is one available. Or some other way to let the original event get called etc..

Thanks,

Comment: That's a common threading problem called *deadlock*.  It happens when you break the contract of an apartment-threaded COM server, like WebBrowser.  Creating one on an STA thread requires you to pump a message loop.  Use the debugger's Debug + Windows + Threads to find out what your threads are doing.

Comment: @HansPassant , thanks for your help Hans, but could you plz give me  few more details, like what should I look for in threads' window and how to use that information for my purpose.

One thing which I forgot to add was that this whole code is running in a different thread than UI. But even running this code on UI thread didn't make any difference.

Comment: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Any one else having any idea on this?

Comment: still waiting if someone can throw some light